# Jquery Cycle Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle

Hey everyone, I'm not the best at Jquery debugging, so I was hoping someone could let me know what this means, and hopefully how to fix it.

I am using jquery Cycle  lite(hosted locally) & Jquery (hosted by google).

My Code is pretty simple:

```
    <div id="slideshow1" class="slider" > 
<img src="/images/slider1.jpg"  /> 
<img src="/images/slider2.jpg" /> 
<img src="/images/slider3.jpg"  />
```

And my Script:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
LINE21-->         $('#slideshow1').cycle()
             });
    </script>
```

Firebug console gives me the following error:

$("#slideshow1") is null)

$('#slideshow1').cycle()\r\ncandypants.ca (line 21)

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have a closing div tag? also are you including the google hosted jquery before the local jquery cycle?

Comment: Yes and Yes, sorry i forgot the ending div tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you including the jQuery script library in your page?  If not, you need to include it.  If so, do you have any conflicts with the use of the $ sign?

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#slideshow1').cycle();
});
```

Comment: No conflict did it!

Thanks a ton!